# TextBox loses its focus when timer is ticking

Tags: asp.net

I put a timer control on a specific section on my page, but every time the timer is ticking, my text box (I have multiple text boxes) in another section loses it focus.

How can I resolve this? I tried placing the timer in a separate update panel.
the code in timer Tick event is

```
 protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((List<AllPostInformation>)Session["AllNewsPostCollection"] != (List<AllPostInformation>)Session["CheckExistData"])
        {
            if ((List<AllPostInformation>)Session["AllNewsPostCollection"] != null)
            {


                List<AllPostInformation> o = new List<AllPostInformation>();
                o = (List<AllPostInformation>)Session["AllNewsPostCollection"];
                rptNews.DataSource = o;
                rptNews.DataBind();
            }
            Session["CheckExistData"] = Session["AllNewsPostCollection"];
        }
    }
```

and on asp page

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upTimer">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="5000" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: to help you, we need to see the code

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the post in this link, [Focus lost on partial postback with UserControls inside UpdatePanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583948/focus-lost-on-partial-postback-with-usercontrols-inside-updatepanel) you will get idea that you need not to put the timer control in the update panel instead put the items that are going to be updated.