# User control retains focus incorrectly after TextChanged postback when UC is contained within a detailsview control

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, ajaxcontroltoolkit, detailsview

I reference a previous post: [Focus lost on partial postback with UserControls inside UpdatePanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583948/focus-lost-on-partial-postback-with-usercontrols-inside-updatepanel/27650018#27650018)
where an excellent solution works perfectly for web-page controls within a form.
However, I have placed my UC inside a detailsview template-field (for Edit+Insert).

The UC contains an UpdatePanel needed to adjust the text-formatting and control's style(s) following the TextChanged event of the UC-textbox (AutoPostback=True) during the Edit-mode and Insert-modes of the DetailsView.

As such, when the DetailsView-control is in Edit-mode, and user changes Text in the UC, the textchanged event is fired and the user-entered value is validated and when OK, the thousounds-separator (comma) are added to the UC-textbox-text, BUT, the focus moves to the next field in the DetailsView and QUICKLY returns back to the UC-control.

This incorrect focus-move(s) does NOT occur when the UC is wrapped in updatepanels as noted in the referenced post since the focus and tabbing order **works perfectly outside of the DetailsView control.**

Here is the aspx markup for the template-field-EDIT (only).

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Initial Mileage" SortExpression="IMilage">
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updpnlIMilage" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" >
    <ContentTemplate>
        <TGANumeric:GANumeric ID="ucnumIMileage" runat="server"
            Caption="Initial Mileage" HideCaption="True" Width="160"
            DisplayMask="999,999" InputMask="999999"
            Enabled="True" IsRequired="False"
            MinNumber="0" MaxNumber="999999"
            Text='<%# Bind("IMilage") %>'
            TabIndex="0"
            />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ucnumIMileage" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

Thanks in advance.  Your comments are welcome.
Thanks...J.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on all the comments in this thread, I want to explain the actual root cause of the tabbing misbehavior.
1)  There were no coding issues or event-issues with the user-control.

2)  There were no coding issues or event-issues with the layering of Master-page, Content-page, Ajax update-panels / nested update-panels, details-view and template-fields containing the user-control.

3)  The real culprit was a small snippet of code where the page adjusts the web-controls on the form based on the "state" (status) of the page/form.  I manage the adjusting of visible and/or enabling of web-controls in a single subroutine in the code-behind so that all of this enabling/disabling visible/not-visible occurs in one place under a set of CASE-statements.
The actual erroneous snippet of code inside the 'sbSetFormState()'-method was messing with the class-variable 'm_eFormState' that actually caused the update panel to re-fire and thus the tabbing got thrown out of sequence.

This was discovered by the great suggestion from 'fnostro' to remove or add functionality features until the mis-behavior exposes itself.
I mark this topic as resolved/closed.
Again, thanks to fnostro !!!

Answer (score 0):

So are you saying your control hierearchy (partial) is:

```
UpdatePanel > TGANumeric:GANumeric > UpdatePanel > TextBox
```

This is an awful lot of overhead to just format a number with a comma, which is the only reason I see for your posting back.  As far as I can tell there is nothing you need from the server, so why post?

Or is there?

My thoughts, lose the update panels, disable the AutoPostback on the Textbox, handle the formatting  client side if it *must* be seen immediately, or leave the formatting to the DetailsView field DataStringFormat when it posts after save.

I'm betting this will clear up any focus issues.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Yes you have the hierarchy correct.  I made a numeric-only UC that may be $$ or thousands and wanted the lost-focus (text-changed) to place the formatted number in the TBox.  Notice $$ can have values such as: $ 4.561.23 or ($ 1,234.56) for negatives AND I have another UC for DATE values which also needs validation on the server since the coding for friendly date input is complex, as you would know. So if we use javascript on blur, then we have to also strip the non-numeric chars on-focus and that is a lot of code to send to the browser. Your comments are welcome. Thx.

Comment: one issue is that modifying the textbox with formatted text is then going to invalidate your previously validated value.  This is a problem.  are you writing for HTML5 ASP.NET 4+ ?  If so just set TextBox.TextMode to an appropriate *type* and that will handle validity checking clientside

Comment: Additionally, with the UC(s) -- I wanted to have all formatting and validation-logic inside the UC.  I also wanted the number or date to be formatted correctly on lost-focus only when the values are valid for their purpose...meaning a USA date of 45883014 is meaningless, whereas 0215 is valid for 02/15/2015 (current year assumed, user enters only mmdd or 031509 for 03/15/2009 -- formatted on lost-focus).  Thanks for your time and your comments are welcome....jd

Comment: comments crossing...sorry...I am not aware of TextMode -- will research and get back to you.  Really appreciate your replies and comments...jd

Comment: Also, generally speaking, *"a lot of code on the browser"* is a moot point and laughable really when we are writing ASP Web Apps.  Between what MS loads and our own useful addins (colorbox, modernizr, jqueryui, etc) the sheer volume of code is astounding, just inspect any aspx page to see what's being loaded.  Anything you can do clientside is going to be faster and cleaner than doing a postback

Comment: I understand the need to contain the formatting and validation within the UC, but try to avoid "reinventing the wheel."  the only reason to turn this into a UC is if you are going to use this UC across multiple pages and then only if the same bound fields are available (unless of course your UC allows for different bound field names programmatically)

Comment: ALso consider formatting in the Bind: `<%# Bind( "IMileage", "{0:F0}" ) %>` or for currency: `<%# Bind( "IMileage", "{0:C2}") %>`

Comment: Please refer to the code at the top of the thread...the Text=<bind> allows the control to be bound differently on any page and the UC-properties allow various properties for the developer to set.  So it appears we veered off the original question -- how to correct the incorrect focus-move(s) on the postback for TextChanged???  thanks.

Comment: Yes, saw that after.  Getting back to topic, if you can't simplify and really need to implement this solution, I cannot say for certain the cause of the focus issue but my best guess is it's associated with the repopulating of the textbox with the formatted text.  Try eliminating UC features until the focus behaves as expected.  Start with a raw textbox with no validation, no formatting, no updatepanels, etc... and then start adding things back and see when the focus issue becomes a problem.

Comment: Thank you, again, for your reply -- really much appreciated.  I think the problem is in the DetailsView and/or template since the tabbing order/focus progression works perfectly without the DVw.  So there is something that textchange occurs moving the focus to the next control and then another event is fired that sets the focus back to the original control, being the UC-textbox.  What event do you think could be firing, and "how" can I discover it??? thanks...jd

Comment: That is the question isn't it...how...I would do as I say above and remove all the functionality, including the UC.  Have just a basic asp TextBox and then starting adding things back. when the bad focus behavior shows up, you have your culprit.  So that's the how.  As for what is causing it, I gave you my thoughts already - I believe it's the formatted text being placed into the TextBox in combination with a whole host of complexity introduced with dual update panels and triggers in conjunction with the UC - you have a maze of things to sort through.

Comment: Thanks.  I have begun to do what you suggested, but added a new page with DetailsView containing the UC-controls to a test-bed project used previously to test the UCs. Defined a number of fields as UC-controls and **guess what -- it works** -- meaning the tab-key moves out of a UC-control, the UC gets formatted  on lost-focus and the next control receives focus as we would expect.  I thank you very much for all your guidance and POV on this topic AND you are VERY SMART with this and hope we can continue with you teaching me and others.  Very nice to have you answer my questions. jd